# knockout help getting external data

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have just finished the knockout tutorials and now I am trying to get data from an external page.

In the tutorial they use this code:

```js
self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", "Standard (sandwich)", "34.95" ),
        new SeatReservation("Paul", "Standard (sandwich)", "14.95" )

       ])
```

And I want to update it to pull from an external file looping through the options:

```js
self.seats = ko.observableArray([
  
  $.get( "scripts/test.js", function( data ) {
     
    
    
     $(data.data).each(function(index, result) { 
  
         new SeatReservation(result.name, result.mealName, result.price )
     })  
     
   })
     
     
  

  )]
```

Where the structure of test is:

```
var data = [
  {
    'mealName': 'Standard (sandwich)',
    'price': '0',
  },
  {
    'mealName': 'Main (sandwich)',
    'price': '34.95',
  }
];
```

What else do I need to do?

I have included jQuery and Knockout on the page.

I also have to run this from file:// as it needs to be sent somewhere

---

So i have updated my code to do this

```js
var newData = ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){
  console.log(item)
  console.log(item.firstName + " " + item.lastName + " " + item.price);
  
  return new SeatReservation(item.firstName, item.lastName, item.price);
        
  
 });
        console.log("here");      
        console.log(newData);
    self.seats(newData);
```

The console is logging the data as expected for item but the return is not doing anything and console.log(newData) returns undefined

why would this be?

Answer (score 1):

With what you have there at the moment, you are throwing away the results from the ajax call.  you will need to do something like

```
$.get( "scripts/test.js", function( data ) {
  self.availableMeals = data;
});
```

However as `self.availableResults` is not a knockoutjs ObservableArray, the page will not respond to changes coming from the server via the ajax call.

you will want to do something like this.

```
self.seats= ko.observableArray();

$.get( "scripts/test.js", function( data ) {
  var newData = ko.utils.arrayForEach(data, function(item){
    return new SeatReservation("", item.mealName, item.price);
  });
  self.seats(newData);
});
```

Comment: actually it makes no sense to have that in available meals it can be called when the array is formed..

So how would I update this to pull from that file

self.seats = ko.observableArray([
        new SeatReservation("Steve", "Standard (sandwich)", "34.95" )
])

Comment: i'm not sure I follow? are you now wanting to update the reserved seats via an ajax call as opposed to the available meals?

Comment: yes i will post as an answer as its too messy in this box